# DataTables horizontal scroll state save

Tags: jquery, datatables

My vertical state save works fine but refuses to save horizontally, All my googling has resulted with no answers.

How do i get ScrollX to stateSave?

Below is my current DataTable

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#example').removeAttr('width').DataTable({
            "ordering": false,
            "searching": false,
            scrollY: '64vh',
            deferRender: true,
            "bInfo" : false,
            scroller: true,
            scrollX: true,
            stateSave: true,
            "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
            "columnDefs": [ {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"} ],

        } );         

    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not handled by default, you might be able to do it on your own with the [`stateSaveCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback) and [`stateLoadCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback) options.

Also check [`stateSaveParams`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveParams) for saved params management.